# MSI is not picking the productcode and productname from .ism file

Tags: installshield

I have updated "ProductCode", "ProductName" and "ProductVersion" of .ism file using install shield and triggered the MSI.

But the MSI is not picking the latest product code, name and verions. Still it is reflecting the old values.

**Old values:**

ProductCode  {**A6CA6D00-21B0-4E0F-BAFF-9C3C8E945C23**}
ProductLanguage1033
ProductName**ANDCSPRT**
ProductVersion**94.04.04.01**

**New Values:**

ProductCode**{A083A8CF-A89C-42B1-9D08-7B76D780C3FA}**
ProductLanguage1033 
ProductName**ANDCPATCH** 
ProductVersion**01.04.00**

From the orca tool, I can see the old values only from the MSI

Comment: Are you using the command line build tool?

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overridden these values in the "***Releases***" view in Installshield, I guess they take precedence over the values found in the  "***General Information***" view (or equivalent - not sure if it is the same in all Installshield versions).

Please check what values are specified for these "properties" in the ***Releases View*** for the particular release you built / rebuilt. Also, after the build, select the specific release you built and go `Tools => Open Release Folder` (or equivalent - not sure of the exact text) to see the MSI you actually built.

[image: Installshield Releases View]

Comment: Product Configurations are build time transformations that always take priority. It's been this way for decades.